# How to make php page refresh only once?

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

I make a page with multiple  inside it..I want went some condition meet then my browser will refresh or reload...

I have tried `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="no-cache">` and `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3">` but it doesn't refresh the `<iframe>` content..So I try this in my php page

```
if ( $value1 != 0 AND $value2 != 0) 
{
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
echo "setTimeout(function() { history.go(0);}, 3000);";
echo "</script>"; 
}
```

and it successfully refresh the browser and the`<iframe>`content...but the problem is my page will keep reloading or refreshing every 3s..

How to make so my browser only refresh once??
Please show me a way...

Comment: use `get vars` in url, for example

Comment: or set a session variable

Comment: im confused, do you want page to refresh once, or iframe to refresh once?

Comment: If your script is inside the iframe it's going to get reloaded and rerun when the iframe is refreshed. When you refresh the iframe the first time you need to pass a parameter to it's URL to tell it not to reload -- but's it's not clear if you know the URL of the iframe, or if it varies. Alternatively use a session variables as Oli says above.

Comment: What's the condition you want the page to refresh on? You can put location.reload(); in some sort of an if statement in your javascript to do this conditionally, but I think knowing the condition will help us give you better answers.

Comment: I want to reload the browser once when 2 value `$POST` to my php page..
It's not working with `location.reload()` as well..
How to use `get vars` in url?? can you give me an example...

Comment: @reza `www.com?var1=1&var2=2`

Comment: @EL : excuse me, i don't get what you mean by `www.com?var1=1&var2=2` example you give..If what you mean is to pars the conditon value to run the `history.go(0)`, I already solved the condition problem..What troubling me now is how to make the never ending refresh to stop after the browser refresh once...

Comment: @reza No, I don't mean to parse. I mean redir to another parameters. For example, `www.com?refresh=yes` redirect to `www.com?refresh=no` with no use of `history()`